Module not found error for aws-exports.js in production build with AWS Amplify and Next.js 13
I'm currently integrating AWS Amplify with GitHub for CI/CD in a Next.js 13 project. My build fails in production due to a missing module error because the aws-exports.js file is automatically generated and included in .gitignore, hence it's not found during the build process.
Error Message:
Module not found: Can't resolve '@/aws-exports'

Environment:

AWS Amplify
Next.js 13

amplify.yml Configuration:
version: 1
frontend:
  phases:
    preBuild:
      commands:
        - npm ci --cache .npm --prefer-offline
    build:
      commands:
        - npm run build
  artifacts:
    baseDirectory: .next
    files:
      - '**/*'
  cache:
    paths:
      - .next/cache/**/*
      - .npm/**/*
backend:
  phases:
    build:
      commands:
        - cd src/app/api
        - npm install
        - npm run build-api
  artifacts:
    baseDirectory: src/app/api
    files:
      - '**/*'
  cache:
    paths:
      - src/app/api/node_modules/**/*

How can I ensure that aws-exports.js is correctly generated and available for the production build, considering it’s ignored by Git due to its presence in .gitignore? Are there any best practices for managing this file in a CI/CD setup with AWS Amplify, especially to avoid exposing sensitive configuration details?
